# HTTP POST file from .NET controller to java rest service

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, multipartform-data

Lately i have been trying to post a file from .net controller through .net controller using HttpClient,

to a Java Rest Service and failed many times as i was unable to send the file in the correct format.

below ajax call in the working jQuery way to invoke the service and pass the file with meta data key.

```
function Upload() {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', document.getElementById("file").files[0])

    var metaData = [{"symbolicName": "DocumentTitle","dataType": "string","value": "Test CSEPF Document"}]
    data.append('metaData', JSON.stringify(metaData));

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://xxx:xx/FileNetCoreRestServices/AddDocument',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger
        }
    });
}
```

Request payload when posted with ajax

```
   ------WebKitFormBoundaryaCyKxSim0zzwhHK7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="4.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf


------WebKitFormBoundaryaCyKxSim0zzwhHK7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metaData"

[{"symbolicName":"DocumentTitle","dataType":"string","value":"Test CSEPF Document"}]
------WebKitFormBoundaryaCyKxSim0zzwhHK7--
```

Now i want the same thing to be replicated in the .net controller side,
As per my research i know that i need to use `MultipartFormDataContent` and `HttpClient` in order to get this working.

below is the .net code i have written in order to upload the file to the service.

```
List<string> lstFilesToBeUploaded = null;
try
{
    string FileTransferApiUrl = "http://xxx:xx/FileNetCoreRestServices/AddDocument";

    lstFilesToBeUploaded = new List<string>();

    string OperatorSourceRootFolderPath = Server.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["UploadLocation"]);

    if (Directory.Exists(OperatorSourceRootFolderPath))
    {
        lstFilesToBeUploaded = Directory.GetFiles(OperatorSourceRootFolderPath).ToList();
    }

    foreach (string filePart in lstFilesToBeUploaded) // improvement - this is sequential, can be made threaded
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("metaData", "[{'symbolicName':'DocumentTitle','dataType':'string','value':'Test CSEPF Document'}]");

            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                byte[] Bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePart);
                var fileContent = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(Bytes));
                fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePart) };
                content.Add(fileContent);

                var response = client.PostAsync(FileTransferApiUrl, fileContent).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var responseData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

When i run this code i get the response as

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * $WSEP: Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: Close Date: Wed, 27 Jun 2018 11:41:39 GMT Server: WebSphere Server: Application Server: Server/7.0 Content-Language: en-US Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 }}
```

I am not entirely sure how the `MultipartFormDataContent` works, it would be helpful if any one points out where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many failed attempts and research i was able to call the service with the file, and below is the working code which i used in order to achieve this.

```
 #region FILENET Upload
    string FileLocation = Server.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FileLocation"]);
    var FileNetRestServiceURL = "http://xxx:xx/FileNetCoreRestServices/AddDocument";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        //Working - Default Values
        //var values = new[]
        //{new KeyValuePair<string, string>("metaData", "[{'symbolicName':'DocumentTitle','dataType':'string','value':'Test CSEPF Document'}]")};

        //Real Values
        var values = new[]
        {new KeyValuePair<string, string>("metaData", "[{'symbolicName':'"+Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileLocation).ToString()+"','dataType':'string','value':'"+Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileLocation).ToString()+"'}]")};

        //Convert the file into ByteArrayContent as the service is expecting a file object
        content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileLocation)), "file", Path.GetFileName(FileLocation).ToString());

        foreach (var keyValuePair in values)
        {
            content.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value), keyValuePair.Key);
        }

        var response = client.PostAsync(FileNetRestServiceURL, content).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        var values = new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("metaData", JsonConvert.SerializeObject("[{'symbolicName':'DocumentTitle','dataType':'string','value':'Test CSEPF Document'}]"))
        };

        foreach (var keyValuePair in values)
        {
           content.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value), keyValuePair.Key);
        }

    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePart));
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "Foo.txt"
    };
    content.Add(fileContent);

    var requestUri = "http://xxxx:xxxx/CSEPFCoreRestServices/addDocument";
    var result = client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;
}
```

}

Comment: This is the error i am receiving `{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  $WSEP: 
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: Close
  Date: Wed, 27 Jun 2018 11:41:39 GMT
  Server: WebSphere
  Server: Application
  Server: Server/7.0
  Content-Language: en-US
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
}}`

Comment: To do it the way your working request is doing it, you might need to convert to Json. You are using Json.Stringify in the working request, but no Json converter in the C# request.  `JsonConvert.SerializeObject("[{'symbolicName':'DocumentTitle','dataType':'string','value':'Test CSEPF Document'}]");`